# How to return response without waiting for downstream in spring integration DSL

Tags: asynchronous, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I've got Integration flow which expose endpoint (inboundGateway), proceed transaction (some transformation) and send to downstream (outboundGateway). How can I return response to upstream directly after received transaction without waiting for transformation and result from downstram? Response like 200 OK (some kind of acknowledge)

```
public IntegrationFlows
   .from(Http.inboundGateway("test").errorChannel("failures").get())
   .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://example.com/test").httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).expectedResponseType(String.class).get())
```

Above code gets transaction, then sends to downstream and finally return response from downstream to upstream. How can I return acknowledge to upstream and then skip response from downstream?